# Self study question on Uniform Distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, uniform-distribution

I am attempting a self-study question on uniform distribution but was not able to make sense of the answers provided after taking an attempt.

Appreciate any help and guidiance please.

**Question**

> An energy company provides electricity with voltage uniformly distributed between 220.0 volts and 250.0 volts. Any voltage level being more than 242.0 volts is dangerous and unacceptable. What is the probability that a randomly selected voltage level is between 245.5 and 248.5, given that it is under the unacceptable level?

**Attempt**

[image]

Comment: Notation: since $X$ was stated to be uniform, $X\sim\text{Unif}(a,b)$ or perhaps $X\sim\text{U}(a,b)$, not $X\sim\text{Dist}(a,b)$.

Comment: Also, draw a picture (on a number line) of the interval the variables is defined on, the interval being conditioned on, and then the interval being asked about.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. I have done so via http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/05/04/536612e23c011.jpg. However, I am still slightly confused. From what I understand, the probability over interval from a to b is constant. I'm really cluely how to proceed on. Appreciate some advice please.

Comment: Maybe you and I are interpreting the word '*under*' differently in the phrase "given that it is under the unacceptable level".

Comment: Hmm.. From what I understand, the "under" in this context means part of. Not sure if my interpretation is right?

Comment: Well I interpreted 'under' to mean 'below' as in the expression 'the temperature is under 242 volts'. But your interpretation, while not idiomatic English, makes more sense as a nontrivial probability question. You'd simply proceed from the definition of conditional probability. What proportion of the values in the conditioning interval (unacceptable) are in that inner interval?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you made a typo when you stated the problem, or if the question was just poorly worded (which sometimes happens), but I think

> "... given that it is **under** the unacceptable level?"

is supposed to mean *given that the voltage is in the unacceptable region (i.e. > 242)*. If this is the case, try using 
$$
Pr(a \leq X \leq b \;\ |  \;\ X > c) = \frac{F(b) - F(a)}{1 - F(c)}
$$ 
to work out the answer.